# How to unit test Akka Agents?

Tags: scala, akka, agent

I'm trying to write a scala class which periodically retrieves data from an external location. I don't care when the data is retrieved, just that it happens every hour. Akka agents are a perfect solution for this but I have no idea how to test them. Here's an example to illustrate my problem:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.agent.Agent
import scala.concurrent.duration._

abstract class Fetcher(implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem) {
  import actorSystem.dispatcher

  private val data: Agent[String] = Agent("")
  def current: String = data.get()

  protected def retrieveData(): String

  actorSystem.scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 1.hour) {
    data send retrieveData()
  }
}
```

---

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import bbc.scala.whitelist.dynamic.Fetcher
import org.specs2._

class FetcherSpec extends mutable.Specification {

  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("TestActorSystem")

  class TestFetcher extends Fetcher {
    override protected def retrieveData(): String = "data!"
  }

  "The Fetcher" should {
    "contain the empty string initially" in {
      val fetcher = new TestFetcher
      fetcher.current must be equalTo ""
    }

    "contain data after the first scheduled update" in {
      val fetcher = new TestFetcher
      Thread.sleep(100)
      fetcher.current must be equalTo "data!"
    }
  }
}
```

That second unit test currently passes but I do not like the Thread.sleep at all! How can I force the scheduled task to happen before making my assertion? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you seen http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.11/scala/testing.html?

Comment: Thanks @SethTisue,  I have seen the document. The TestKit seems to be focused on `Actor`s but I'm using `Agent`s. I'm quite new to Akka so maybe there is something in the test kit that I can use but at the moment I can't figure out what that is. Is there a method that can manually force the scheduler to run?

Comment: It seems like you are actually testing the scheduler functionality rather than _your_ functionality which seems pointless imho. I'd rather test the `retrieveData` but if you insist you could parameterise the `Fetcher` class with a `frequency` parameter which you can set to a shorter value in your tests

Comment: Thank you very much @JamesSharp, that's a very good point. The code within my scheduler in my actual project is a little more complicated than just a call to `retrieveData` but if I move this to the subclass then it can be fully tested there. Cheers!

Comment: There is a function called `awaitCond` in the TestKit, as pointed out by @SethTisue. This is a slightly cleaner way to test than the Thread.sleep, but is still pretty awkward in a unit test.